# Where can I find tests that validate the output of popular statistical software? (e.g. R, SPSS, SAS)

Tags: r, spss, validation, software, quality-control

This has been difficult to search on Google. I've looked on R's website as well. I assume there are test suites that validate that R, SPSS, SAS, et al are giving the right output for a given analysis? And perhaps suites that compare their output on the same data and models? How would we know if we could trust their results otherwise? Where can I find some systematic testing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: When in doubt you just have to either a) run your model in a different software package or b) program your model from scratch and compare results.  For the record, I have very rarely found pre-canned routines to give false results.  Usually when I have a problem it is because I didn't fully understand what the functions where doing or was trying to do something stupid.

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld In the case of `R`, your confidence may be well placed for the base programs, but is decidedly too optimistic for user-contributed programs, which is the vast majority of the code.  Some of the latter have enormous, glaring bugs; yet others more insidiously work fine on small problems but fail on larger "real-world" ones, or have subtle numerical problems that cause loss of precision in output.

Answer (score 2):

It's also a good idea to check algorithm documentation or, for open source, to read the code if in doubt as packages differ in exact definitions, terminology, and computational details, especially for edge cases.  All this may not matter, though, for routine usage.

In the case of SPSS Statistics, detailed algorithm doc is available from the help menu or online in the IBM Infocenter.